# Gitlab CI only: does not work as expected with anchors and .extends

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am currently working with Gitlab-CI and I have encountered a Strange behaviour.

I am currently trying something along the lines of this:

```
.when-to-use: &WhenToUse
 - merge_requests
 - master
 - main
 - develop
 - /.*/
 - tags

job1:
  only:
    *WhenToUse
    variables: [ $JACOCO == "true" ]
```

My expected behaviour is, that the only block contains the WhenToUse list as well as the variables block.

This does not work how matter how I try it (if anyone knows how I could accomplish this, that would be very much appreciated) but that is not actually the Strange behaviour I found.

I then changed this .yml to:

```
.when-to-use: &WhenToUse
  - merge_requests
  - master
  - main
  - develop
  - /.*/
  - tags


.testWrapper:
  stage: test
  only:
    *WhenToUse

job1:
  extends: .testWrapper

job2:
  extends: .testWrapper
  only: 
    variables: [ $JACOCO == "true" ]
```

Now according to this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#exclude-a-key-from-extends) this should result in the behaviour, that job1s `only:` contains the `.whenToUse` list (which it does) and job2s `only:` contains the `.whenToUse` list (which it doesnt) + `variables: [ $JACOCO == "true" ]` (which it does), meaning that it is not actually extended but overwritten.

Does anyone know why this behavour occurs and maybe even how to fix it?

The indentations are all correct, as the pipeline is executed but just not in the way I would have expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem is that I technically overwrite `only` while doing that.

The solution to the problem is doing it as follows:

```
.when-to-use: &WhenToUse
  - merge_requests
  - master
  - main
  - develop
  - /.*/
  - tags


.testWrapper:
  stage: test
  only:
    refs:
      *WhenToUse

job1:
  extends: .testWrapper

job2:
  extends: .testWrapper
  only: 
    variables: [ $JACOCO == "true" ]
```

Adding in `refs:` (which I think is the proper way anyway) means that no part is overwritten and the checks are all executed properly.